# possible bug in python xml element tree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have come across a strange error within my python code where the element tree library does not pick up text within the XML file, consider the following scenario:

```
<user.ISOCountryCode>UK</user.ISOCountryCode>
<user.RegistrationDate>2013-10-16T12:51:36Z</user.RegistrationDate>
<user.PK>16318168107</user.PK>
```

using code similar to the below, user.PK for a certain clause is never picked up, instead a None is returned, the text definitely exists within the XML as above, it is always the same elements that have this problem, is there a fix for this error?:

```
    context = ET.iterparse(xmlLoc,events=("start", "end"))
    context = iter(context)
    event,root = context.next()

    for event, element in context:
    if primeKey in element.tag:
    pk = element.text
        for element in root:
            if element.text:
                elementText = element.text.replace('"','')
                elementText = elementText.replace('|','')
            else:
                 elementText = element.text
            data[element.tag] = elementText
    for subElement in element:
        subElementText = ''
        if subElement.text:
        subElementText = subElement.text.replace('"','')
        subElementText = subElementText.replace('|','')
        else:
        subElementText = subElement.text
        data[subElement.tag] = subElementText
        if subElement.tag == keyTag:
        key = str(subElementText)
    element.clear()
    if len(data) > 0 and key and pk:
        result = json.dumps(data)
        data.clear()
        file.write(pk + "|" +  key + "|" +  result + "\n")
        root.clear
```

Comment: Your code is not indented correctly - e.g. the if blocks

Comment: I do not see any place where the variable `pk` is assigned to. Are my searching skills failing or did you paste in code that cannot work?

Comment: no it was pasted in wrong, corrected

Comment: Please provide a short, complete, standalone program that demonstrates the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org/.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i was iterating over root and deleting it when i should have been iterating over sub elements, here is the working version i figured out

```
def convertXMLInterparse(xmlLoc,elementName,keyTag,file,primeKey):  
    key = ''
    pk = ''
    data={}
    context = ET.iterparse(xmlLoc,events=("start", "end"))
    context = iter(context)
    event,root = context.next()
    for event, topElement in context:
        try:
            if primeKey in topElement.tag:
                pk = topElement.text        
            if event == "end" and topElement.tag == elementName:
                for element in topElement:
                    elementText = ''
                    if element.text:
                        elementText = element.text.replace('"','')
                        elementText = elementText.replace('|','')
                    else:
                        elementText = element.text
                    data[element.tag] = elementText
                    if element.tag == keyTag:
                        key = elementText
                    for subElement in element:
                        subElementText = ''
                        if subElement.text:
                            subElementText = subElement.text.replace('"','')
                            subElementText = subElementText.replace('|','')
                        else:
                            subElementText = subElement.text
                            data[subElement.tag] = subElementText

                            if subElement.tag == keyTag:
                                key = str(subElementText)
                            subElement.clear()
                        element.clear()
                    topElement.clear()
                    if len(data) > 0 and key and pk:
                        result = json.dumps(data)
                        data.clear()
                        file.write(pk + "|" +  key + "|" +  result + "\n")
                root.clear()
            except Exception as e:
                jeetl.log("exception in convertXMLInterparse " + str(e) + "\n" + "string  : "  + " File " + xmlLoc ,True)
                continue
```